# Python argparse store data after "stop-symbol" as a string

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a specific task with recognising command line arguments, but I don't know how to implement this.
Now I have something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Execute task')  
parser.add_argument("-q", "--queue", dest="queue", default='default', help="Task queue to use")
parser.add_argument("-w", "--wrap", dest="wrap", default=None, help="Command to execute") 
(options, args) = parser.parse_known_args()
```

`-w` is used for saving bash command. It can contain quotes, minuses and other special symbols, so it will be more convenient to do something like this:

```
mycmd.py -q default / mysqldump -u name -p pass > mydump.sql
```

So everything is after a symbol `/` just converts to string in one argument.
Is it possible to implement? Python 2.7.x is used.

Comment: I think it's not possible. You'll still need to quote `>` so bash won't interpret it as mycmd.py stdout redirection.

Comment: You can use double quotes and get command in a string. Something like:    `mycmd.py -q default -w "mysqldump -u name -p pass > mydump.sql"`

Comment: `argparse` just parses the list of strings `sys.argv`.  So it is at the mercy of how the shell breaks up the command line.